# What is the best way to use subfolders in AWS with Rails ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Default ActiveStorage configuration for S3 only asks for the bucket, region, and access keys. I would like to use subfolders for both stage and prod within my one S3 bucket. Is this possible with ActiveStorage?

Comment: Not at the moment, no.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that was both my suspicion and my fear